# Authenticating iPhone application with Rails application

Tags: iphone, ios, ruby-on-rails, devise, restkit

I have been doing research on this for quite some time and have not been able to solve my issue so I figure i'd ask.  I have searched the other questions here on stackoverflow and other articles and they don't seem to get me in the right direction.

Here is what I am trying to do.  I have a Rails 3 application that is only providing data in JSON format.  The data will be entered by only 1 user so access to it will be very limited.  I am using Devise so that it is protected via authentication.

I also have an iPhone application that will access this data.  Since the Rails 3 application has username/password protection the iPhone application needs a way to authenticate with the application.

I have looked in to token authentication in Devise, but can't seem to get it to work.  I have a loading symbol and it just spins and doesn't return any data.  I also looked at http basic authentication.  Again, haven't had any luck.  On the iPhone side I am using ASIHTTPRequest.  Following is what I am using for posting via the authenticity token:

```
//the url variable below is defined in my code but I did not paste that part
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"auth token" forKey:@"authenticity_token"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

When I tried http basic authentication I passed a username and password and that didn't work as well with the same issue and not returning data.  I am sure I am missing something, but I can't find the information I need to get this working.  I took a look at RestKit, but it seems to have a lot more then I need.

I only need the iPhone application to access the JSON data with it being protected on the Rails 3 side.  The iPhone user will not need to sign in via a sign in form or be able to create, update or delete any data.  It is strictly read only.  Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you using devise on rails side?

Comment: yeah I am using devise on the rails side.

Comment: If the API is strictly read-only(for methods like show, index etc), why do you need authentication?
You can specify in your controllers to authenticate only for destructive methods such as create/update/destroy.
If you need authentication from the mobile client, I can guide you to a simple token authenticate that devise offers.

Comment: Hassan, thanks. I forgot about specifying in the controller to only authenticate for destructive methods. The reason I would like to authenticate for reading the data from the mobile client is to restrict access to just my iphone application. It's only listing events so it isn't something anyone would really want. If you do have a guide to a simple token authenticate that devise offers and how the iphone application can use it that would be good. As you can see from my code above I have tried this previously. I set up the token_authenticatable in devise and was passing an authenticity token.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to using basic auth

In you api/application controller on the rails side add

```
 before_filter :check_auth


  def check_auth
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username,password|
      resource = User.find_by_email(username)
      if resource.valid_password?(password)
        sign_in :user, resource
      end
    end
  end
```

On the iOS side you should set the Authorization header on the request object:

ASIHTTP supports this out of box. Luck you.

```
[request setUsername:@"username"];
[request setPassword:@"password"];
```

or you can add them to the URI of your request.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://username:password@allseeing-i.com/top_secret/"];
```

this will allow a sign in with basic auth and further controllers will get your user from the session

then on the ios side you can just pass credentials like you would with any basic auth system.

I recommend using SSL/HTTPS in production or credentials will be passed in plain text or base64.

Comment: Thanks I will try this out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately it couldn't get it work.  The first issue is when I set my post values in my ios application (username and password).  When it does this it tries to create an event as opposed to sending the authentication params, authenticating and then reading the events.  This is more then likely because I am setting postvalues in my ios application: [request setPostValue:@"email" forKey:@"username"].  I do see that the iphone application is passing the params. Finally, I get an 401 status code of unauthorized, so it is

Comment: No u dont use post values you need to set it as the authentication header. See: http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/